# Getting actual value from db on page_load

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Ive got 2 controls:

- ProductList
- CardInfo

In product list there are products. After clicking on a button buyNow product is added to the basket and number of points on users card is reduced.

In CardInfo there is actual users point count.

The problem is that Im calculating number of points in CardInfo on PageLoad event. It means that its calculated before ProductList_OnClick event so that its always one step to late with showing actual users points count.

How should I go through such a problem ?

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the asp.net [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events)

The control events fire after pageload. A possible solution for your problem is to have the point calculation after the control event such as on PreRender.

Comment: Thanks, I simply didnt think about using it there

Answer (score 0):

Do it in Page_Load

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //now do your db stuff
}
```

I haven't used the onclick event even once for this exact reason. I like control, and with page.ispostback, you have control.